# How to install Node 14 version on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, installation

I want to install Node.js version 14 on Windows but it is not installing instead it is showing below screen.

[image]

But when I try to install Node.js v17, it is opening installation wizard by which I can install Node.js but this is not happening for Node.js 14. How can I install Node.js v14?
I downloaded the exe from https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v14.17.3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've downloaded the `exe`, there's no installation needed - you already have the executable, and as you can see, it's operational - when you run it, you get Node.js' REPL.

If you want to "properly" install Node.js you could download and run the MSI from the link instead of the exe.

Comment: MSI is resolved the problem -https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.3/node-v14.17.3-x64.msi

Comment: Can you tell what is the diff between exe vs msi?

Comment: @ezhil The `msi` available there is the installer. The `exe` available there is Node.js itself. Essentially, the `msi` extracts the `exe`, copies it to the right location, and IIRC, sets up some environment variables to add it to the PATH

Answer (score 15):

It is easier to use nvm for node installation. It allows you to quickly install and use different versions of node via the command line

It is available on [Linux/Mac](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) and [Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

You can find the setup file in the [releases](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases) section and install it

To install node v14 you just need to execute 2 comands

```sh
nvm install 14
nvm use 14
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you get an executable file when you download it? You might have downloaded the `zip archive` instead of the installer. There can be many ways to install node into your Windows machine.

## Using nvm (recommended)

You can use `nvm` to keep multiple versions of node and toggle between them when needed.

```
nvm install 14
nvm use 14
```

Ref: [NVM Readme](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md)

---

## Using MSI Installer

Download the `msi` installer from the website [Previous Releases page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) if you want a specific older version. Here is a link for [v14.18.2-x64](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.18.2/node-v14.18.2-x64.msi).

---

## Using Zip Archive (the hard way)

If you want to do it by using the file you already downloaded, what you can do is:

1. Save that `exe` file to a specific location you want (It is recommended to save all the executable binaries in `bin` directory in your `User` directory, similar to how we do in Linux systems).
2. Copy the path to that file (e.g., `C:\Users\erajendr\bin\node.exe`).
3. Search for *Edit the system environment variables* in Cortana search.
4. Look for a variable with name "Path".
5. Double click on the variable.
6. Add the copied path to the list of existing paths there.

You can test if this works by typing `node` in a fresh new terminal/cmd.

Ref: [How to add Path in Windows 10](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/)